# global operator + override clash detection

Tags: c++, overriding, operator-keyword

My code is is clashing with a 3rd party library. I define this:

```
inline __m128 operator + (__m128 a, __m128 b)
{
    return _mm_add_ps(a, b);
}
```

but get

```
error C2084: function '__m128 operator +(const __m128,const __m128)' already has a body
```

I can't change the 3rd party library and they don't #define anything which identifies this operator as having been defined. Is there a way (perhaps using SFINAE) that anyone knows of to allow their definition to prevail?

Comment: First, do you see *why* this is clashing? And assuming so, this may seem a silly question but why are you trying to implement this if they provide it in the first place?

Comment: It's clashing because they're the same, which is fine, their one does the same thing mine does. The library in question is optional, so if it's not used, I need the override to be defined in my header.

Answer (score 2):

Any reason why you want to define that operator? Should it not come defined from whatever library defines the type `__m128`?

Operators are really part of the interface of the type of the arguments. They should not be defined by external parties (in this case that is *you*).

SFINAE cannot help you there at least not directly, since SFINAE applies only to templates, and you really don't want templates there (you don't want to provide `operator+` for *any* type, do you?). With enough effort you can build something that would seem to work but it would depend on whether the compiler sees the definition of the operator in the library on each and every use of `+` with those types in your source code.

If the operator is defined in a library that is linked in some but not all use cases, you could wrap the definition of the operator with an `#ifdef` and use a define to control whether the operator is defined or not at build time.

Comment: Unfortunately __m128 is a built in compiler type which can't be derived from. At the moment I manually comment out my override when using the library which also defines it, but if that library isn't being used then it has to be manually enabled again.